# refactor the rspec tests

Tags: ruby, rspec

I have written a unit tests as below.

```
describe Youtube::Metadata do
  let(:subject) { SampleMetadata.from_text(open(url)) }
  context "when url is passed" do
    let(:url) { "http://www.sample.com" }

    describe "It should return all values from the site" do
      its(:id) { should eql "234" }
      its(:url) { should eql "www.sample.com" }
    end

    context "Given a html file with id property" do
      let(:html) { File.join(PAGES, 'youtube', 'sample1.html') }
      let(:subject) { Youtube::Metadata.from_text(File.read(html)) }

      it "should return unique value from id property" do
        subject.unique_id.should eql "65155c6e-ba11-42fc-bb91-53520176d2a8"
      end
    end

    context "Given a html file with rel:canonical property" do
      let(:html) { File.join(PAGES, 'youtube', 'sample2.html') }
      let(:subject) { Youtube::Metadata.from_text(File.read(html)) }

      it "should return unique value from rel=canonical content property" do
        subject.unique_id.should eql "65155c6e-ba11-42fc-bb91-53520176d2a8"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I need to refactor it so that I dont have to repeat the below statement in each and every tests cases.

```
let(:subject)   { Youtube::Metadata.from_text(File.read(html))
```

I tried it with before block but it didn't work.

> Actually the first context we pass url and the second set of context
>   we pass filename. Also I am not sure whether I need to make it as a
>   single context (which is passing file name contexts, ie. last two) and describe it.

What would be the right way to do it??

Comment: you set an [explicit subject](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-1/docs/subject/explicit-subject) with `subject { … }`, not `let(:subject) { … }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're asking good questions but let's take a step back regarding testing in general.  You're looking to DRY up your tests because you recognize duplicate code - great.  Tests are meant to be easy to read and easy to follow.

Thankfully `rspec` gives you access to things like `context` and `describe` in order for you to separate your tests into parts.  Your tests are heavily separated and you're using let variables (which in turn create instance variable scopes) for things you're only using in a single test.

To me that seems overkill and you're adding complexity to a test that is otherwise self contained in a normal `it` block.

For instance, this seems like a more structured set of tests:

```
describe Youtube::Metadata do
  include Helpers
    # ... omitted ... 

    context "Given a html file with id property" do
      it "should return unique value from id property" do
        subject = file_loader('youtube','sample1.html')
        subject.unique_id.should eql "65155c6e-ba11-42fc-bb91-53520176d2a8"
      end
    end

    context "Given a html file with rel:canonical property" do
      it "should return unique value from rel=canonical content property" do
        subject = file_loader('youtube','sample2.html')
        subject.unique_id.should eql "65155c6e-ba11-42fc-bb91-53520176d2a8"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Then just create a helper like so:

```
module Helpers
  def file_loader(dir, filename)
    file = File.join(PAGES, dir, filename)
    Youtube::Metadata.from_test(file)
  end
end
```

Comment: This would be fine if I had one directory for youtube in PAGES. But if I have multiple directories like nbc, bbc etc.. then this wont work I guess. One way would be to pass that class name in the helper module and make it dynamic. But again I will have to create a folder name same as class name...

Comment: It will work, you would just send additional arguments to your `file_loader` method.

Comment: Or i will have to save the path of my newly created folder in the specs in a variable and pass to this helper method

Comment: I updated my answer - you can also use `*dir` if you have multiple directories you need to send in

Comment: That was a nice thought. I liked it. anyway.

Comment: I am trying to learn Rspec by doing these.. Do you suggest any good book which explains very well and covers advanced topics also..

Comment: I'm not familiar with too many RSpec books but I can tell you my greatest source of 'how should I do this' has been the discourse repo [here](https://github.com/discourse/discourse/tree/master/spec) - some of the best ruby code out there.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`shared_examples`](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-0/docs/example-groups/shared-example-group):

```
shared_examples_for "unique id parser" do |sample_file, expected_id|
  let(:html) { File.join(PAGES, 'youtube', sample_file) }
  subject { Youtube::Metadata.from_text(File.read(html)) }

  it "parses unique id property" do
    expect(subject.unique_id).to eql expected_id
  end
end

context "Given a html file with id property" do
  it_behaves_like "unique id parser", 'sample1.html', "65155c6e-ba11-42fc-bb91-53520176d2a8"
end

context "Given a html file with rel:canonical property" do
  it_behaves_like "unique id parser", 'sample2.html', "65155c6e-ba11-42fc-bb91-53520176d2a8"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

First, use another name for the second and third ":subject" because you already has one in the outter block.

Second, you really need 'sample1.html' and 'sample2.html'? If not, change to 'sample.html' and move both 'let's up.

Third, check if you had some problem with lazzy load (change let to let!)

Comment: Yes.. I need both sample1.html and sample2.html since both are required for differnt scenarios testing. So I have prepared a dummy data for it.

Comment: Mainly I am looking to avoid repetition of let(:subject)   { Youtube::Metadata.from_text(File.read(html)) since it serves the same result.

Comment: If you don't need more than these, you can create :html1 and :html2. If you need up to sample99.html, we may think in another solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Group it with another context:

```
describe Youtube::Metadata do
  # ...
  context "given a html file" do
    subject { Youtube::Metadata.from_text(File.read(file)) }

    context "with id property" do
      let(:file) { File.join(PAGES, 'youtube', 'sample1.html') }

      it "should return unique value from id property" do
        # ...
      end
    end

    context "with rel:canonical property" do
      let(:file) { File.join(PAGES, 'youtube', 'sample2.html') }

      it "should return unique value from rel=canonical content property" do
        # ...
      end
    end
  end
end
```